# keep geography coords from ajax

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

good evening,
j tries to retrieve the data from the user but the problem iç that i can not handle the coords because of "," longitude and latitude, i do not know how to treat these give, i tried with parsefloat but without result, thank you
code controller action :

```
    public ActionResult GetNeaarByLocations(string CurrentLat, string CurrentLng)
    {
        using (GeolocationTestEntities context = new GeolocationTestEntities ())
        {
            var CurrentLocation = DbGeography.FromText("POINT(" + CurrentLat + " " + CurrentLng + ")");
            //var CurrentLocation = DbGeography.FromText("POINT(36,806494799999996 10,181531600000001)");
            var places = (from u in context.schoolinfo orderby u.Location.Distance(CurrentLocation)
                          select u).Take(4).Select(x=>new schoollinfo(){ Name = x.name ,Lat = x.Location.Latitude, Lng = x.Location.Longitude,Distance = x.Location.Distance(CurrentLocation)});
            var nearschools = places.ToList();
            return Json(nearschools , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

and this is code Ajax :

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetNeaarByLocations")",
                    dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ CurrentLng:currentLatLng.longitude, CurrentLat: currentLatLng.latitude }),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != undefined) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            addMarker(item["lat"], item["lng"], "Click to get  directions");

                        })
                    }
                },
                failure: function (errMsg) {
                    alert(errMsg);
                }

            });
```

thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

we need to convert lng & lant to double

```
   var currentLatLng = position.coords;
                var Lat = currentLatLng.latitude;
                var Lng = currentLatLng.longitude;
                var LatDouble = parseFloat(Lat);
                var LngDouble = parseFloat(Lng);
```

for Ajax is to delete att stringify

```
 data: JSON({ CurrentLng:LngDouble , CurrentLat: LatDouble  }),
```